# changing text color daily using css or html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to change the color of a text automatically on a daily basis. I am pretty sure I can get this working in javascript, but I was wondering whether there is a simple css or HTML solution?

Comment: You will need javascript to perform all the logical calculations for the date

Answer (score 2):

#### HTML: *not possible*

`HTML` is a markup language to structure content, and doesn't perform any dynamic functionality as described.

---

#### CSS: *maybe* if the user keeps the page open for days and days

`@keyframe` animation and `timing-function` can maybe do the trick, by having it animated over however many milliseconds in a number of days.

But since `CSS` animation will always reset each time a new user visits, it shouldn't really work as described. The color change won't persist between sessions, between users, between days.

---

#### JavaScript: the only *client-side* option

You could achieve this effect from the server side, say, with PHP: calculate the date, assign a color, and apply to the frontend.

Otherwise, JavaScript—being the only dynamic component out of the three (HTML, CSS, JS)—is the only way to achieve this.

You could do a few different things, should you choose JavaScript:

1. Randomize the color HEX or RGA each day
2. Assign a particular color value per day of the week
3. Assign a particular color per day of the year
   .
   .
   .

and then some.

As you mentioned you could get this working in JS, I'm skipping the code example.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the code would be something like this:

```
window.setInterval(() => {
    let date = new Date(); // get current date and time
    if(date.getHours() === 23 && date.getMinutes() === 59){
        // change text color here
    }
}, 60000); // Repeat every 60000 milliseconds (1 minute)
```

Comment: Actually I think this is not a proper answer since the question want's CSS approaches.

Comment: "using css, HTML or javascript"

Comment: The actual context of the question is *I am pretty sure I can get this working in javascript, but I was wondering whether there is a simple CSS or HTML solution?*

Comment: If you have any solution with css or HTML, I will be happy to upvote it

Comment: As far as I know, there is no solution by those approaches, but this post will answer the question neither.

Comment: Check the question's title again. He is accepting js suggestions too...

Comment: The fact is that the question's scope encompasses a solution in JS too, as may be inferred by its title. Although he mentions he is pretty sure he can get it working in JS, it does not eliminate JS from the scope, especially because "can get it working" means he has not coded a solution in JS yet. Thus, an answer in JS is also welcome. If it wasn't, JS wouldn't be mentioned in the title in the first place.